# c3.js charts in backbonejs view not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js, requirejs, c3.js

I have problem with implementation [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) charts into my backbone view.

**My code inside main.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'libs/lodash/lodash.min',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        'd3': 'libs/d3',
        'c3': 'libs/c3',
        'templates': '../templates',
    },
    shim: {c3: { deps: ['d3'], exports: 'c3' }}
});
```

**then in view:**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/reports/ReportsCollection',
    'text!templates/reports/reportsTemplate.html', 
    'd3',
    'c3',
], function(_, Backbone, ReportsCollection, reportsTemplate, d3, c3){
console.log(c3);      // OUTPUT IS UNDEFINED
var ReportsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.getElementById("content"),
    render: function(){


      var reports = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reports'));
      var reportsCollection = new ReportsCollection(reports);
      this.el.innerHTML = _.template( reportsTemplate,{data : productsCollection.toJSON()} );

      c3.generate({
          bindto: '#chart',
          data: {
          columns: [
              ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
              ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
          ]
        }
      });
    },
  });
    return ReportsView;
});
```

I see d3js and c3js are properly loaded but in console got error `Cannot read property 'generate' of undefined`

I will be very grateful with any help or opinion!

Comment: how do you know that c3js is properly loaded? have you console.logged its value inside the render method? Are you positive that the template is properly loaded as well? Can you try changing the dependencies order to see if either the collection or template are failing to return a valid AMD variable?

Comment: Thanks for answer... I see in developers tools in network card: d3js and c3js are loaded as last javascripts then is loaded template. I had before working charts from http://www.chartjs.org/ same loaded like now and it was working properly...

Comment: I made a little experiment myself and had to write a shim to make it work. Inside requirejs.config, added `shim: {c3: {
   deps: ['d3'],
   exports: 'c3'
  }}`. I've seen c3 trying to do this in its own code, but in my case, it didn't work out of the box.

Comment: I have updated code but it shows same error... I have no idea why sorry for bothering you

Comment: what happens if you put `console.log(c3)` before declaring `var ReportsView`? does it show on the console as Object {version: "0.4.8"..` etc? Do you know if there's a global c3 object somewhere in your app that might be overwriting the local c3 object?

Comment: it is undefined ...I have updated code...

Comment: If the shim solved it for @amenadiel, then it should work. In case you haven't done it, try clearing the cache and refresh...

Comment: please, console.log the value of ReportsCollection and reportsTemplate. One of those might be failing to export, therefore d3 and c3 are in the wrong variables.

Comment: If I do console.log(reportsTemplate); ==> I have html template.... by the way this template is properly loaded.. and then console.log(reportsCollection ); ==> I have array hm I don't know.

Comment: You could try adding a shim for d3 too, so it would read shim: `{'d3': {
   exports: 'd3'
  }, 'c3': { deps: ['d3'], exports: 'c3' }}`.

Comment: not solve my problem... So Amenadiel I need to have output from console.log(c3) before declaring var ReportsView something like {version: "0.4.8"..`  ?

Comment: ah guys sorry ! It is working now ...

Comment: @Makromat Can you clarify what was the problem?

Comment: Ah have loaded after template jqueryui and after that d3,c3 further I changed the order to template-c3-d3-jqueryui...